# Speeding up the JSON load using Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, performance, get, slickgrid

I am trying to load JSON data from my service URL into Slickgrid for my custom application and the load part is alone taking a long time.

My below code is taking around 7 seconds for 200,000 rows for the load, which I couldnt afford.

Any way to speed it up?

```
<script>
  var slickdata=[];
$(function () {
     console.log(new Date());

   $.ajax({    
       type: "GET",
       url: "http://localhost:8082/com.oracle.rest/api/crud/select/allrows",   
       dataType: 'json',
       error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           // debug here
           alert("hi this is error message"+errorThrown);
           console.log(jqXHR);
        },
       success: function(data) {

        console.log(new Date());
        var len=data.length;

        for (var i = 0; i <len; i++) {
               slickdata[i] = {
                  EMPLOYEE_ID: data[i].EMPLOYEE_ID,
                  FIRST_NAME: data[i].FIRST_NAME,
                  LAST_NAME: data[i].LAST_NAME,
                  EMAIL: data[i].EMAIL,
                  PHONE_NUMBER: data[i].PHONE_NUMBER,
                  HIRE_DATE: data[i].HIRE_DATE,
                  JOB_ID: data[i].JOB_ID,
                  SALARY: data[i].SALARY,
                  COMMISSION_PCT: data[i].COMMISSION_PCT,
                  DEPARTMENT_ID: data[i].DEPARTMENT_ID,

            };
         }
        console.log(new Date());    
       }
   })
})
</script>
```

EDIT - The service URL returns the 200 thousand rows of employee information from Oracle DB using Servlets.

Thank you,
B

Comment: Paginate your data.

Comment: Is the majority of the time taken in getting the data or int the for loop? And...is that 2 hundred thousand records or 2 million? If it is 2 million then 7 seconds may not be unreasonable

Comment: Its 200 thousand. The time is more while fetching and almost no time during the loop.

Comment: Pagination is not an option. I need to show all the records in a single page. They need to sort, filter on the whole data and pagination doesnt help on that. Thanks.

Comment: If, as you say, the majority of the time is on the remote url and not the loop as shown then there is nothing you can do with the code shown unless you have access to the remote controller. I suggest you start a new question showing your remote controller code and requesting help at that end.

Comment: Why copy the data? slickdata=data would do the same? Also, as asked above, do you have server time reponses? is the fech faster if you get it as text without json conversion? And finally, if your user refuse to have pagination even if no human can read 200 000 lines, you still can make a lazy loading:of part of the page loads without data then the blank are filled when you scroll, like the load of map in google maps. You can also still filter and sort with pagination, you just have to do it on server-side

Comment: I am a database guy, and got to work in Java, Ajax, JS only for the past two months. I thought lazy loading will not work in filter and sort. Can you redirect me to a lazy loading example please? Much appreciate your clear response.

Comment: http://6pac.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example6-ajax-loading.html

Comment: http://6pac.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example6-ajax-loading-yahoo.html

Comment: Also check at the server end you are using compression for the payload. For text or JSON this will greatly reduce the size transferred.